# Can I move left and right header in curve?

Tags: curve-class

I do NOT want parallel headers, meaning left and right header are opposite eachother. I want the left header to be lower than the right header. Is it possible to do that in Curve?[image]

My code:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass{curve}

%% Swedish Date
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}

\rightheader{
Kakaka 13\\
50666 Barsa\\
0744444444\\ 
asdf.asdf@gmail.com
}

\leftheader{
Sparbanken\\
Kalle Karlsson\\
Alingsås
}

%\title{\today}
%\subtitle{\today}

\begin{document}

\makeheaders[t]
%\maketitle

\makerubric{info}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The documentclass `curve` is intended for doing a curriculum vitae. Your layout reminds me of a letter. For letters, there are other document classes which will put the address in the right place for envelopes with windows.

Comment: I just thought there might be an easy way to move the headers with that it would have been perfect for me.

Comment: There is \raisebox.  Even if curve doesn't align baselines, you can adjust the height or depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start `\leftheader` with the line

```
\mbox{}\\[2cm]
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{curve}

%% Swedish Date
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}

\rightheader{
Kakaka 13\\
50666 Barsa\\
0744444444\\ 
asdf.asdf@gmail.com
}

\leftheader{
\mbox{}\\[2cm]
Sparbanken\\
Kalle Karlsson\\
Alingsås
}

%\title{\today}
%\subtitle{\today}

\begin{document}

\makeheaders[t]
%\maketitle

%\makerubric{info}

\end{document}
```